# Datagridview Row Color change based on Text c# windows application form

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpfdatagrid

```
DataRow row = table.NewRow();                                           // Insert New row in datagridview

    if (ByteArrayToHexString(buffer).StartsWith("AA") && ByteArrayToHexString(buffer).Substring(6, 2).StartsWith("11"))
    {

        table.Rows.Add(row);                                                // Add new row
        row["Source"] = string.Format("{0}", "ABUS_L/R");                   // Insert source name in row
        row["System Time"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff");         // Insert time in row
                                                                          //row["Source"] = ByteArrayToHexString(buffer).Substring(9, 2);     
        row["T.S Begin"] = ByteArrayToHexString(buffer).Substring(8, 8);    // Insert TS Begin
        row["T.S End"] = ByteArrayToHexString(buffer).Substring(16, 8);    // Insert TS End
        row["Length"] = ByteArrayToHexString(buffer).Substring(24, 2);      // Insert length Field
        row["Data"] = ByteArrayToHexString(buffer).Substring(26, 2);        // Insert Data field
        row["CRC"] = ByteArrayToHexString(buffer).Substring(28, 2);         // Compare CRC field with Protocol & validate the information
        row["CRC_PC"] = crc8.ComputeChecksum(buffer);                       // Compute & compare CRC generated by PC                                                                                                                // Add new row
        //dataGridView1.Update();                                           // Update datagridview
    return;

    }

    //Case for ABUS_RK

    if (ByteArrayToHexString(buffer).StartsWith("AA") && ByteArrayToHexString(buffer).Substring(6, 2).StartsWith("12"))
    {
        table.Rows.Add(row);                                                // Add new row

        row["Source"] = string.Format("{0}", "ABUS_RK");
        row["System Time"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff");
    //row["Source"] = ByteArrayToHexString(buffer).Substring(9, 2);

        row["T.S Begin"] = ByteArrayToHexString(buffer).Substring(8, 8);
        row["T.S End"] = ByteArrayToHexString(buffer).Substring(16, 8);
        row["Length"] = ByteArrayToHexString(buffer).Substring(24, 2);
        row["Data"] = ByteArrayToHexString(buffer).Substring(26, 2);
        row["CRC"] = ByteArrayToHexString(buffer).Substring(28, 2);
        row["CRC_PC"] = crc8.ComputeChecksum(buffer);
        //table.Rows.Add(row);
        //dataGridView1.Update();
    return;

    }
```

Hello,

I want to Change the row Color based on the text data in the column. Suppose I have text as "ABUS_R/L" I want to make whole row Green, for "ABUS_RK" whole row as yellow.

I tried the following Syntax in for Loop & if Loop:

```
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

However, it is changing the whole form color instead of only changing the row color.

So can anybody tell me how I can do same?

Answer (score 1):

You need to target the specific `row`, not the whole `DataGridView`

```
row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: I am unable to perform this Operation. I am not getting DefaultCellStyle Option for row.

Comment: That's because your row is of type `DataRow` which belongs to `DataTable` this has no colour property. 
You need to be targeting the row of your `DataGridView` however without any code related to the `DataGridView` we are unable to help

Comment: do i Need to handle this in Datagridview ? Not in datatable? I will update the Code

Comment: Yes - The `DataGridView` is where the colour property exists. The `DataGridView` is the control which gets and displays the data from a `DataTable`

Comment: Ok. I will add new thread to this question & insert complete Code. i am unable to insert changed Code here

Comment: Hello. No it didnt. May be my error is in Looping. So i am initiating new thread where i can put my whole Code & it will be clear for you to suggest changes as well